How can I connect a BLE sensor to a mobile device within 700-800 milliseconds and receive data from the sensor within 700 milliseconds?
I am using a BLE sensor for a mobile application. If I use a 1500 millisecond connection interval, I can connect to the sensor and receive notifications from it. However, if I use a 700 millisecond connection interval, I can connect to the sensor but cannot receive notifications from it. What should I do?
I am trying to reduce the connection interval timings from 1500 milliseconds to 1400, 1300... 700 but i cannot able to receive the notification from the sensor

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is your BLE sensor battery powered? Lower connection intervals  increase power consumption. This could be why your peripheral refuses to do work faster.  Have you checked that Bluetooth LE connection interval negotiation has been successful and what the result is?

We are using a BLE sensor for a mobile application. The sensor's advertisement interval is 1500 milliseconds, and it goes offline 800 milliseconds after connecting to the mobile application. Within this period, we need to collect notifications from the BLE sensor.
